# Translate PHP API POST call to Python using requests

Tags: php, python, api, post, python-requests

How can I make the following PHP API endpoint post request in Python instead:

```
$cSession = curl_init();
$cFile = curl_file_create('my_receipt.jpg'); //Path to the file which will be uploaded
$post = array('file_contents' => $cFile);

curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.tabscanner.com/{your_api_key}/process');
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 

$result = curl_exec($cSession);

if (curl_errno($cSession)) { 
    $result = curl_error($cSession); 
}

curl_close($cSession);
echo $result;
```

I have tried the following:

```
import requests as rq
import json
import os

api_key = 'xxxx'
url = 'https://api.tabscanner.com/{}/process'.format(api_key)

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/'
img = PROJECT_ROOT + 'receipt1.jpg' # I presume this needs to be read as an image file, rather than just the filename

result = rq.post(url, data=json.dumps({'file': img}))
print(result.text)
```

Which results in the following output:

`{"message":"ERROR_FORM_PARSER: Error: missing content-type header","status":"failed","status_code":4,"success":false,"code":406}`

Comment: You missed the content type header. [Docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)

Comment: How do I add that into the `requests.post` call though? Also the PHP example specifies `CURLOPT_HEADER` as `false`, so I presume it doesn't accept a header.

Comment: @KlausD. I have tried `rq.post(url, headers={'file': img})`, `rq.post(url, data=json.dumps({'file': img}), headers={})`, `rq.post(url, data=json.dumps({'file': img}), headers=False)`, etc. None of which work.

Comment: You should really read the error message and the docs I linked.

Comment: I have and no matter what I try to include for the `headers` param I get the same error as my original question. I have even looked at the `requests` source code to see if I am adding the headers incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Below works for me

```
files = {'receiptImage': open(RECEIPT_FOLDER+'/receipt.jpg', 'rb')}
resp = requests.post(process_endpoint, files=files)
```